# Pine Script - Perfect Pivot Strategy for Trading View

Tags: pivot, pine-script

I'm trying to make a strategy that will buy and sell right on pivots. Don't rush with conclusions, I know it can't be used in real trading ;)
The idea is, that we can use the perfect buy signals based on pivots, to look for the custom sell signal which will not be affected by bad buy signals, and vice versa.

I tried many different approaches, but the signal comes with delay equal to the length of the pivot. How can we force the buy/sell condition right at the bar where pivot was detected? 
Thank you!

P.S.: Here is what must be closest to the solution, but it still doesn't work

```
legs = input(17)
pHi = pivothigh(legs, legs)
pLw = pivotlow(legs, legs)

longCondition = bar_index[barssince(pLw)]
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = bar_index[barssince(pHi)]
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to warp time and have the broker emulator go back 17 bars in time to issue orders in the past? Can't be done.

Comment: What if we use pivothigh(17, 1) so it will close at the next bar after pivot? It will use real-time bars without warping time

Comment: As you said in your question, you can issue the order when the pivot is detected, which is determined by the number of right legs you use.

Comment: It would be awesome if the possibility to do it would be added to the emulator. It would help to find much cleaner signals. Please, consider this. 
Thank you in advance!